# I need to maintain a user login in firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a page that autheticate the login, but i have two types of users, one adm e other a shopkeeper, after login, they are redirect to their respective pages, how can i maintain their login after redirect the pages after logging? I'm using firebase.
i'm trying to use persistence, but i dont know how it works properly.

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function(){

  firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(function(){
    var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
    var senha = $("#inputSenha").val();

    if(email != "" && senha != ""){
    var login = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha);
    login.then(function(result){
      window.location.href = "";
      

    }).catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      alert("não foi possível conectar");
      console.log(errorMessage);
    });
  }else{
    window.alert("Preencha todos os campos!");
  }
    
  }).catch((error)=>{
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    alert("Erro percistencia");
    console.log(errorMessage);
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep an active session, we usually save a token in the "local storage" and make a request to the server to check if the token is linked to a user.